# How to send all value of checkboxes on server?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML code is generated by Angular JS via `ng-repeat`:

```
 <li ng-repeat="(key, item) in data.conditions_list" ng-class="{active: item.active}">
            <span class="sbrand-checkbox">
                <input ng-checked="item.active" type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.conditions[item.id]">
            </span>
            <label>{{item.name}}</label>
  </li>
```

This code sets checkboxes on active state if `ng-checked="item.active"`. It works.

When I checked any unchecked element and submit with checked by default form I see:

```
["conditions"]=>
  array(1) {
    [5]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
```

So, it means is sent only thta checkbox which I have cheked. Others was not sent on server.

I can do something like as:

HTML:

```
<input ng-checked="isChecked(item.active, item.id)" type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.conditions[item.id]">
```

Angular JS:

```
$scope.isChecked = function (item, id){
    if(item.active){
        $scope.formData.conditions[id];
    }
};
```

And after send form with `$scope.formData.conditions`

Answer (score 0):

This is how the browser behaves. It do not submits the unchecked checkbox value. It has nothing to do with angularJs or Javascript.

You can treat the absence of checkbox value in the request as unchecked on the server.

An alternative way is to maintain hidden fields for each checkbox and set its value on checkbox change and submit these hidden fields to the server instead of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I love angular but when it comes to checkboxes and radio boxes they stink. I would resort to jquery. Insert the dom element that contains the inputs, and you will get back an array of values:

```
function getChecked(dom) {
    var boxes = $(dom).find('input[type="checkbox"]').map(function()
        {
            return $(this).prop("checked")
        }
    );
    return boxes;
}
```